# Can't find tokyo.html in MasterPage gallery

Tags: 2013, master-page, design-manager, edit

I have set `Tokyo.master` as my Master Page. Now I want to customize it. If I try to edit and save it I get a warning it will no longer be based on Site Definition. So I need to edit a `.html` page of the same name, correct?

Well `tokyo.html` does not exist. I see `seattle.html` and `oslo.html` but no `tokyo.html`.

And I'm sure I did not delete it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint pages are, by default, associated with site definition files. When a master page is customized in SharePoint Designer, it is no longer associated with the site definition. This can result in additional administrative work following future updates or upgrades to SharePoint, which is why you see this message. You can always reset the master page to its site definition, if necessary.

Your changes will appear on every page attached to this master page unless those pages were customized directly.

Hence you can directly work on the master page and save it. The best practice is

1. Copy `Tokyo.master` and Rename it as `TokyoCustom.master`
2. Then change the elements in `TokyoCustom.master`
3. Save, publish and approve
4. Change the master page to `TokyoCustom.master`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it normal for `Tokyo.html` to be missing? Moreover, how do I create a `tokyo.html` that is associated with `tokyo.master`? All articles I see provide a way for the other way around - creating a master page from html page.

Comment: Yes. I have never seen `Tokyo.html` file. I have always worked with by creating a copy of `Seattle.html` file.

Comment: I did like you mentioned: created a copy called `tokyo_custom`, edited and overrode site definition. Proceeded to set the new `tokyo_custom` as default master page and custom master page in sp designer. But when I go to the sp site settings > master page, here I see that `seattle` is set to master page for both user and system. Earlier it was `tokyo`. How did this happen and how to set it to `tokyo_custom`? `tokyo_custom` is not an option in the drop down to change master page.

Comment: I had not published it. It seems this option is only available in the site settings and not in SharePoint designer. Can't figure out how to approve it.